# Stop using Development Release of Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, development

Some time ago I updated my system to the development release of Ubuntu using these instructions:

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/about-ubuntu/C/upgrade.html

"If you would like to install and test the latest development version of Ubuntu before it is released, press `Alt+F2`, type `update-manager -c -d` into the box and click Run. If a development release is available, an Update button will appear in the Update Manager. **Click it to upgrade** to the development version."

However, now my machine is always trying to update to the latest development packages causing randomness that I can't afford. Could someone please tell me how to have Ubuntu STOP updating to the development release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your `Update manager` then click at `Settings` . This action will leads to you a new Window . in that at Updates TAB look at the last option , i mean At **Notify me of a New Ubuntu Version** and set it to Normal release . 
[image: At Notify me of a New Ubuntu Version]